# How to save PWA state when App gets quit in background?

Tags: ios, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I have a simple website that I've made into a Progressive Web App. I save it to the homescreen on my iPad, open the App and navigate to another page. If I return to the homescreen and reopen the App it is still on the 2nd page. If I open a bunch more Apps in between, then when I return the App will reset to the first page. How do I work around this to save the page when it returns?

I'm ok with it being reset when a user force quits the app by swiping up on the app switcher but I'd like it to save the state in every other case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should make use of the [Page Lifecycle API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api) to save state when you detect that you're being closed, and then restore state (including the previously open URL) when you detect an initial launch.

There are some caveats in that article about what's supported in Safari vs. some other browsers, but in general, the building blocks you need should be there.

Comment: Thanks, a little more complicated than I’d hoped but better than being impossible